# Scale image in keras when providing no input shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to resize an image in a neural network and I don't provide Input shape. Is it possible? My last code:

```
def exp_no_input_shape():

    kernel_size = (3, 3)
    a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
    b = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
    inp = Input(shape=[a, b, 3])

    layer1 = Conv2D(3, kernel_size, strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation='relu')(inp)

    resize_layer = tf.image.resize_images(layer1, [tf.shape(layer1).eval(session=tf.compat.v1.Session())[0]*2, tf.shape(layer1).eval(session=tf.compat.v1.Session())[1]*2], method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)
    layer2 = Conv2D(3, kernel_size, padding='same', activation='relu')(resize_layer)

    return Model(inp, layer2)
```

It gives the error: `Error converting shape to a TensorShape: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Tensor'.`

Also, I tried this earlier:

```
def exp_no_input_shape():
    kernel_size = (3, 3)

    inp = Input(shape=[None, None, 3])

    layer1 = Conv2D(3, kernel_size, strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation='relu')(inp)

    resize_layer = tf.image.resize_images(layer1, [tf.shape(layer1).eval(session=tf.compat.v1.Session())[0]*2, tf.shape(layer1).eval(session=tf.compat.v1.Session())[1]*2], method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)
    layer2 = Conv2D(3, kernel_size, padding='same', activation='relu')(resize_layer)

    return Model(inp, layer2)
```

It gives the error: `You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and shape [?,?,?,3]`

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55814061/resizing-images-with-dynamic-shape-in-tensorflow. Helpful?

Comment: @dvir-samuel Yes, it answers my question, but I realized that I can't use tf.shape() for some reason, so this answer is not helpful in the end